# Strange access log reported by loggly

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, loggly

I am working on aws waf to block the bad bots. I am using loggly service as well to check the access logs of the server and bad requests.

But I am not understanding about the following log, what this log is for and is this bad?

Please check this image
[image]

Logs is showing some internal ip as host and accessing unknown url. This is somethign strange for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a malware user-agent ; you can consider it as bad-bot. You cannot avoid such things.. There are bots which keep scanning ports etc. As per one of the estimates 25-50% of overall internet traffic(not including videos and images) is bots.

Just ignore these log messages.